# How to extract column names from .txt file properly

Tags: python, pandas, txt

I am using the below-mentioned code in order to **print the column names** of the dataset ( [.txt file](https://1drv.ms/t/s!ArUrNl7BkVgtiGLba3i-TJVv8lJ5?e=F9jDhV) ) but it prints whole rows.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("HotelRec100.txt")
print(df.columns)
```

[The result is here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AxEI.png)

**a few rows from the data:**

"{""hotel_url"": ""Hotel_Review-g194775-d1121769-Reviews-Hotel_Baltic-Giulianova_Province_of_Teramo_Abruzzo.html"", ""author"": ""Lagaiuzza"", ""date"": ""2016-01-01T00:00:00"", ""rating"": 5.0, ""title"": ""Baltic, what else?"", ""text"": ""We have spent in this hotel our summer holidays both in summer 2014 and 2015- I was with my husband and my child ( 4 years old at present). I do really recommend this place- Staff si high qualified, Kind and really helpful- Animation staff get You involved, but always with discrection - Miniclub si super and activities offered are interesting and smart- Rooms clean, with AC and balcony- Restaurant offers a great selection of food - always. The beach si extremly closed to the hotel - Miniclub area offers some gazebos to have shade for kids- A lot of bicycles are available for free- I am completely satisfied of this hotel- Go in lime this!"", ""property_dict"": {}}"
"{""hotel_url"": ""Hotel_Review-g194775-d1121769-Reviews-Hotel_Baltic-Giulianova_Province_of_Teramo_Abruzzo.html"", ""author"": ""ashleyn763"", ""date"": ""2014-10-01T00:00:00"", ""rating"": 5.0, ""title"": ""Excellent in every way!"", ""text"": ""I visited Hotel Baltic with my husband for some bike riding in the area, thinking it would just be another hotel. I was so wrong. We don't have children, but were so amazed at the attention to detail and kindness we experienced from every member of the staff. It was truly amazing."", ""property_dict"": {""service"": 5.0, ""location"": 5.0, ""value"": 5.0}}"
"{""hotel_url"": ""Hotel_Review-g194775-d1121769-Reviews-Hotel_Baltic-Giulianova_Province_of_Teramo_Abruzzo.html"", ""author"": ""DavideMauro"", ""date"": ""2014-08-01T00:00:00"", ""rating"": 5.0, ""title"": ""The house of your family's holiday"", ""text"": ""I've travelled quite a numbers of hotels but this is the best place you can achieve with an excellent ratio quality/money. The equipe is really excellent. The restaurant's staff and the chef are perfect. Menu is always varying. Bar service is really fantastic. On the beach rather than in the hotel, anything is perfect and our holiday went like a dream. Although prices could seems quite high, you must consider that you could even forget your wollet at home. You'll never be required to spend any money. Kids are always happy and miniclub staff is really efficient. My daughter crying for our leaving could explain better what I'm writing."", ""property_dict"": {""service"": 5.0, ""cleanliness"": 5.0, ""sleep quality"": 5.0}}"

Is there anyone who can help me to solve the issue?

Comment: Show the first few rows.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Copy/Paste the first few rows into your question. We're not going to go downloading random files from the internet :)

Comment: There's only one column. The strings consist of dictionaries in each.

Comment: @inquirer is there any way to make columns like "hotel_url", "author", "date" and so on according to their given values?

Comment: @NihadHuseynov can't find a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.txt` file does not have a column. When loaded into pandas, the first record is taken as column name. Use below to avoid it.

```
df = pd.read_csv('HotelRec100.txt', header = None)
```

You can give any column name by using `df.columns = ['MY COLUMN']`

Comment: Is there any way to make columns like "hotel_url", "author", "date" and so on according to their given values?